# Obtaining value in real time from simplexml output data and using it to trigger a camera with php

Tags: php, arrays, xml

Hello guys how are you doing? I have this project I have been working on for quite some times. It's an alarm and IP camera integration. So far I have been able to connect with the alarm system to receive XML output and have been able to use SimpleXML to parse it into an array with this code:

```
 <?php
//timeout limit
set_time_limit(0);

//Creating Socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
   // echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br />";
} else {
   // echo "OK.<br />";
}

//echo "Attempting to connect to the socket'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, '192.168.43.50', 10001);
flush();
if ($result === false) {
   // echo "socket_connect() failed.<br />Reason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "<br />";
} else {
  //  echo "OK.<br />";
}
$in = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r<br />";
$in .= "Host: 192.168.43.50\r<br />";
$in .= "Content-Type: application/xml; encoding=UTF-8\r\n";
$in .= "Accept: application/xml\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r<br />\r<br />";
$out= '';
while (socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in))){

file_put_contents("intrusion.txt",socket_read($socket, 4096));
    $out = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("intrusion.txt",1,NULL,2))or die ("Error: Cannot create object");

    print_r ($out)."</br></br>";
    flush();
    ob_flush();

}
/*foreach ($v->PlatformIdentification->DeviceIdentification as $out) {
  $DeviceName = $out->DeviceName;
  $Detection = $out->DeviceName;
}*/
socket_close($socket);

/* Camera code 
function openCamFeed($zone)
{
    $camIP = array(
        'Z1'    =>  '192.168.43.50:10001', // :if port is needed
        'Z2'    =>  '192.168.43.51',
        'Z3'    =>  '192.168.43.52',
        'Z4'    =>  '192.168.43.53',
        'Z5'    =>  '192.168.43.54',
        'Z6'    =>  '192.168.43.55',
        'Z7'    =>  '192.168.43.56',
        'Z8'    =>  '192.168.43.57',
        'Z9'    =>  '192.168.43.58',
        'Z10'   =>  '192.168.43.59',
        'Z11'   =>  '192.168.43.60',
        'Z12'   =>  '192.168.43.61',
    );
//echo $zone.'<br /><br />';
    /*if ($zone != '')
    {
        header("Location: http://".$camIP[$zone]);
    }
}*/
?>
```

So right now I'm having difficulties on how I can get node values from the output condition the value to trigger IP of a camera in the web browser. Here is the simplexml output:

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [PlatformIdentification] => SimpleXMLElement
>   Object ( [DeviceName] => Chevron Esc [DeviceCategory] => Sensor
>   [DeviceType] => SPIDR APU ) [PlatformStatusReport] => Array ( [0] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [PlatformIdentification] => SimpleXMLElement
>   Object ( [DeviceName] => Chevron Esc.H1 [DeviceCategory] => Sensor
>   [DeviceType] => SPIDR Hyperzone ) [Status] => SimpleXMLElement Object
>   ( [DeviceState] => Secure [CommunicationState] => OK [UpdateTime] =>
>   2017-08-12T11:19:19.248 ) [DeviceStatusReport] => SimpleXMLElement
>   Object ( [DeviceIdentification] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [DeviceName] => Chevron Esc.H1.Z1 [DeviceCategory] => Sensor
>   [DeviceType] => SPIDR Zone ) [Status] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [DeviceState] => Secure [CommunicationState] => OK [UpdateTime] =>
>   2017-08-12T11:19:19.248 ) ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [PlatformIdentification] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [DeviceName] =>
>   Chevron Esc.H2 [DeviceCategory] => Sensor [DeviceType] => SPIDR
>   Hyperzone ) [Status] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [DeviceState] =>
>   Secure [CommunicationState] => OK [UpdateTime] =>
>   2017-08-12T11:19:19.248 ) [DeviceStatusReport] => SimpleXMLElement
>   Object ( [DeviceIdentification] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [DeviceName] => Chevron Esc.H2.Z2 [DeviceCategory] => Sensor
>   [DeviceType] => SPIDR Zone ) [Status] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [DeviceState] => Secure [CommunicationState] => OK [UpdateTime] =>
>   2017-08-12T11:19:19.248 ) ) ) ) ) SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [DeviceDetectionRecord] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [DeviceIdentification] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [DeviceName] =>
>   Chevron Esc.H1.Z1 [DeviceCategory] => Sensor [DeviceType] => SPIDR
>   Zone ) [Detection] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ID] => SZ003
>   [DetectionEvent] => Intrusion [UpdateTime] => 2017-08-12T11:19:34.650
>   ) ) ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [DeviceDetectionRecord] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [DeviceIdentification] => SimpleXMLElement
>   Object ( [DeviceName] => Chevron Esc.H2.Z2 [DeviceCategory] => Sensor
>   [DeviceType] => SPIDR Zone ) [Detection] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [ID] => SZ004 [DetectionEvent] => Intrusion [UpdateTime] =>
>   2017-08-12T11:19:34.650 ) ) )

Thats just the simplexml output of two zone. If it increases we will have more array created for the other zones and we have close to 12 zones in the project I'm working on and the information i will be working with in the xml file is this:

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [DeviceDetectionRecord] => SimpleXMLElement
>   Object ( [DeviceIdentification] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [DeviceName] => Chevron Esc.H1.Z1 [DeviceCategory] => Sensor
>   [DeviceType] => SPIDR Zone ) [Detection] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [ID] => SZ003 [DetectionEvent] => Intrusion [UpdateTime] =>
>   2017-08-12T11:19:34.650 ) ) ) SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [DeviceDetectionRecord] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [DeviceIdentification] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [DeviceName] =>
>   Chevron Esc.H2.Z2 [DeviceCategory] => Sensor [DeviceType] => SPIDR
>   Zone ) [Detection] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ID] => SZ004
>   [DetectionEvent] => Intrusion [UpdateTime] => 2017-08-12T11:19:34.650
>   ) ) )

The camera will only trigger when it detects an intrusion message with a corresponding device name in the xml output.

Thank you for your respective feedback.

Below is the real xml output

OKay Nigel thank you below is the xml data i wanna process:

When Everything is ok with the equipment i have the xml below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>ras</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR APU</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>ras.H1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Hyperzone</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-08-13T19:32:45.157</UpdateTime> </Status> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification> <DeviceName>ras.H1.Z1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-08-13T19:32:45.157</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport>
```

When there intrusion i have the one below: which is the one i want to extract its information, like the DeviceName, DetectionEvent which will be condition to trigger the camera watching over the area

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<DeviceDetectionReport>
 <DeviceDetectionRecord>
 <DeviceIdentification>
 <DeviceName>ras.H1.Z1</DeviceName>
<DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> 
<DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> 
</DeviceIdentification> 
<Detection> 
<ID>SZ001</ID> 
<DetectionEvent>Intrusion</DetectionEvent> 
<UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-08-13T19:32:44.864</UpdateTime> 
</Detection>
 </DeviceDetectionRecord> 
</DeviceDetectionReport>
```

UPDATED
New code

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

//timeout limit
set_time_limit(0);

//Creating Socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
   // echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br />";
} else {
   // echo "OK.<br />";
}

//echo "Attempting to connect to the socket'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, '192.168.43.50', 10001);
flush();
if ($result === false) {
   // echo "socket_connect() failed.<br />Reason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "<br />";
} else {
  //  echo "OK.<br />";
}
$in = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r<br />";
$in .= "Host: 132.168.43.50\r<br />";
$in .= "Content-Type: application/xml; encoding=UTF-8\r\n";
$in .= "Accept: application/xml\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r<br />\r<br />";
$out= '';
while (socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in))){

file_put_contents("intrusion.txt",socket_read($socket, 4096));
    $out = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("intrusion.txt",1,NULL,2))or die ("Error: Cannot create object");
    //print_r ($out)."</br></br>";
//$doc = new SimpleXMLElement ( $out );

if (isset ( $out->DeviceDetectionRecord )) {
    /*  $devname = "<strong>".$out->DeviceDetectionRecord->DeviceIdentification->
        DeviceName."</strong>" . PHP_EOL."</br></br>\n";
        //echo "Device:" . $devname;*/

    $identity= "<strong>". $out->DeviceDetectionRecord->Detection->
        ID ."</strong>". PHP_EOL."</br></br>";
        echo "ID:" .$identity;
    $detect = "<strong>".$out->DeviceDetectionRecord->Detection->
        DetectionEvent ."</strong>". PHP_EOL."</br></br>";
        echo "DetectionEvent:" . $detect;
    $date= "<strong>".$out->DeviceDetectionRecord->Detection->
        UpdateTime ."</strong>". PHP_EOL."</br></br>";
        echo "UpdateTime:" .$date;

        $deviceName = $out->DeviceDetectionRecord->DeviceIdentification->
DeviceName;
        $zone = explode('.', $deviceName)[2];

                /****** Camera code **********/
                            function openCamFeed($zone)
                            {
                                $camIP = array(
                                    'Z1'    =>  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7FxORx05Ns', // :if port is needed
                                    'Z2'    =>  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00A4vjZ7dkY',
                                    'Z3'    =>  '192.168.43.52',
                                    'Z4'    =>  '192.168.43.53',
                                    'Z5'    =>  '192.168.43.54',
                                    'Z6'    =>  '192.168.43.55',
                                    'Z7'    =>  '192.168.43.56',
                                    'Z8'    =>  '192.168.43.57',
                                    'Z9'    =>  '192.168.43.58',
                                    'Z10'   =>  '192.168.43.59',                                   
                                    'Z11'   =>  '192.168.43.60',
                                    'Z12'   =>  '192.168.43.61',
                                );
                            //echo $zone.'<br /><br />';
                                if ($zone != '')
                                {
                                    header("Location: http://".$camIP[$zone]);
                                    echo "<video target='_blank' width='320' height='240' autoplay controls>";
                                            echo "<source src=".$camIP[$zone].  "type='video/mp4'>";
                                        echo    "<object width='320' height='240' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf'>";
                                            echo    "<param name='movie' value='http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf' /> ";
                                                echo "<param name='flashvars' target='_blank value='config={'clip': {'url':".$camIP[$zone]."',' 'autoPlay':true, 'autoBuffering':true}} /> ";
                                            ///<p><a href='%StreamURL%">view with external app</a></p> 
                                        echo"   </object>";
echo "</video>";
                                //echo "<iframe align='middle' height='450px' width='900px' target='_blank' src=".$camIP[$zone]."></iframe>";
                                }
                            }


                openCamFeed($zone);

}
else {
    print_r ($out)."</br></br>\r\n";
    //echo "Nothing detected" . PHP_EOL;
} 

    flush();
    ob_flush();




}
/*foreach ($v->PlatformIdentification->DeviceIdentification as $out) {
  $DeviceName = $out->DeviceName;
  $Detection = $out->DeviceName;
}*/
socket_close($socket);


?>
```

NEW ERROR OUTPUT
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 21: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag Devic line 21 in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 30

Warning: simplexml_load_string():

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 30

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 21: parser error : Premature end of data in tag DeviceIdentification line 20 in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 30

Warning: simplexml_load_string():

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 30

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 21: parser error : Premature end of data in tag DeviceStatusReport line 19 in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 30

Warning: simplexml_load_string():

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 30

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 21: parser error : Premature end of data in tag PlatformStatusReport line 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 30

Warning: simplexml_load_string():

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 30

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 21: parser error : Premature end of data in tag PlatformStatusReport line 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 30

Warning: simplexml_load_string():

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 30
Error: Cannot create object
RESULT
Failed loading XML String not started expecting ' or " Malformed declaration expecting version Blank needed here parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected Start tag expected, '<' not found Failed loading XML String not started expecting ' or " Malformed declaration expecting version Blank needed here parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected Start tag expected, '<' not found Start tag expected, '<' not found Failed loading XML String not started expecting ' or " Malformed declaration expecting version Blank needed here parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected Start tag expected, '<' not found Start tag expected, '<' not found Couldn't find end of Start Tag UpdateTime line 17 Premature end of data in tag Status line 14 Premature end of data in tag PlatformStatusReport line 8 Premature end of data in tag PlatformStatusReport line 2 Failed loading XML String not started expecting ' or " Malformed declaration expecting version Blank needed here parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected Start tag expected, '<' not found Start tag expected, '<' not found Couldn't find end of Start Tag UpdateTime line 17 Premature end of data in tag Status line 14 Premature end of data in tag PlatformStatusReport line 8 Premature end of data in tag PlatformStatusReport line 2 Start tag expected, '<' not found Failed loading XML String not started expecting ' or " Malformed declaration expecting version Blank needed here parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected Start tag expected, '<' not found Start tag expected, '<' not found Couldn't find end of Start Tag UpdateTime line 17 Premature end of data in tag Status line 14 Premature end of data in tag PlatformStatusReport line 8 Premature end of data in tag PlatformStatusReport line 2 Start tag expected, '<' not found Start tag expected, '<' not found

OUTPUT

```
ationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-09-17T16:24:58.547</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>FD525R-103848</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR APU</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>FD525R-103848.HZONE-1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Hyperzone</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <Stat
us> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-09-17T16:25:18.532</UpdateTime> </Status> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification> <DeviceName>FD525R-103848.HZONE-1.ZONE-001</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState>
<CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-09-17T16:25:18.533</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification> <DeviceName>FD525R-103848.HZONE-1.ZONE-002</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>O
```

SOLUTION

the XML output generated by APU is being truncated
A TCP connection should be treated as a stream. Individual TCP packets are not messages. You can see a similar issue here:
https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/171941-parsing-xml-over-tcp-ip

So what do you think is the problem here?

The solution we have used is to have an object that reads the TCP stream and writes complete XML messages. The object works by keeping track of the XML structure. When the end tag is received for the top-level XML entity, it is treated as a complete message.

For example:

```
<DeviceIdentification>

  <DeviceName>CUSTOMNAME.HZONE-1.ZONE-2</DeviceName>

  <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory>

  <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType>

</DeviceIdentification>

<Detection>

  <ID>SZ002</ID>

  <DetectionEvent>Intrusion</DetectionEvent>

  <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-10-08T15:12:34.000</UpdateTime>

</Detection>
```

The first line  would indicate a new message is starting and then the top level XML entity is . The stream would be gathered and assembled as a complete message until the  tag is received.

Comment: It would be easier if you provided a sample of the XML that you need to process rather than the contents of the SimpleXML data..

Comment: Thank you Nigel the output of the simplexml is what i want to process

Comment: Can you give the original XML and NOT the output of SimpleXML.  It's more likely that someone can solve the problem with some test data and not a dump of the processed data.

Comment: OKay Nigel thank you below is the xml data i wanna process:

Comment: Wooooooow!  @NigelRen you are the bomb. I have been having sleepless night over this for over two months now... Please i want you to do something for me, i wouldn't mind a thip for this job well done. I wanna save this output in a variable then condition the variable by comparison to run the camera's ip in the web browser, or if i could make it run the live feed of the camera in a window like vlc... Please save me finally on that. Then please drop your Kuntakt number lets talk better. I will be looking forward to your reply. I like yooooou so much you don't know what you have done yet..

Answer (score 0):

Using SimpleXML is going to be easy as your structure looks fairly simple.  I've done some code, which starts from the point of the XML having been retrieved (so the data at the top will be retrieved by your existing code).

This is the code which will check the XML for an event...

```
function checkForIntrusion ( string $xml )  {
    $doc = new SimpleXMLElement ( $xml );
    if (isset ( $doc->DeviceDetectionRecord )) {
        $detection = ["Device" => $doc->DeviceDetectionRecord
                                    ->DeviceIdentification
                                    ->DeviceName,
                "ID" => $doc->DeviceDetectionRecord->Detection->ID,
                "DetectionEvent" => $doc->DeviceDetectionRecord
                                    ->Detection->DetectionEvent,
                "UpdateTime" => $doc->DeviceDetectionRecord->Detection
                                    ->UpdateTime

        ];
    } else {
        $detection = false;;
    }

    return $detection;
}
```

Which is used in the following...

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DeviceDetectionReport>
    <DeviceDetectionRecord>
        <DeviceIdentification>
            <DeviceName>ras.H1.Z1</DeviceName>
            <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory>
            <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType>
        </DeviceIdentification>
        <Detection>
            <ID>SZ001</ID>
            <DetectionEvent>Intrusion</DetectionEvent>
            <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-08-13T19:32:44.864</UpdateTime>
        </Detection>
    </DeviceDetectionRecord>
</DeviceDetectionReport>
XML;

$detection = checkForIntrusion($xml);
if ( $detection != false )  {
    echo "Device:" . $detection["Device"] . PHP_EOL;
    echo "ID:" . $detection["ID"] . PHP_EOL;
    echo "DetectionEvent:" . $detection["DetectionEvent"] . PHP_EOL;
    echo "UpdateTime:" . $detection["UpdateTime"] . PHP_EOL;

}
```

This checks for a `DeviceDetectionRecord` and will output...

```
Device:ras.H1.Z1
ID:SZ001
DetectionEvent:Intrusion
UpdateTime:2017-08-13T19:32:44.864
```

This code do the processing of what to do next - capture video or send a message.

I'm not sure how you plan to use this, but it's also dependent on how you display the video.  If your running this from a web page, you may be able to set a segment of the page to the video stream from the camera.

Update:

Zone mapping...
The function at the bottom (which is commented out - so put this function back in and remove the code I previously added) `openCamFeed` should be able to do what you need, you just need to extract the zone out of the deviceName.  You can do this by...

```
$zone = explode('.', $deviceName)[2];
openCamFeed($zone);
```

As you can't use `header()` to jump to another page, you can use an iframe instead...

```
<iframe src ="http://$camIP[$zone]/default.asp" width="100%" height="300">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

(This is from https://www.cctvcamerapros.com/Embedding-IP-Camera-Web-Page-s/326.htm, so I'm not sure if it's compatible, but worth a try).  If this doesn't work, you can try it without the `/default.asp`.

Comment: Wooooooow! Nigel you are the bomb. I have been having sleepless night over this for over two months now... 
Please i want you to do something for me, i wouldn't mind a thip for this job well done. I wanna save this output in a variable then condition the variable by comparison to run the camera's ip in the web browser, or if i could make it run the live feed of the camera in a window like vlc...

Please save me finally on that. Then please drop your Kuntakt number lets talk better. I will be looking forward to your reply. I like yooooou so much you don't know what you have done yet...

Comment: I've changed the code to be a function will returns `false` if nothing found, or  an array containing the event data.  Not sure how this integrates with the rest of what you have, but the return from the function should flag when something needs to be done.

Comment: Thank you @Nigel.... Check up to see the code you sent first. I just made a little adjustment. But when i parse the value into variable and tried to condition it to call a camera IP in browser i get error.

Comment: I just posted the code i used and the error is this: 

Notice: Use of undefined constant ras - assumed 'ras' in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 52

Notice: Use of undefined constant H1 - assumed 'H1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 52

Notice: Use of undefined constant Z1 - assumed 'Z1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 52

Comment: Line should be `if ($detect == "ras.H1.Z1")){`, you need to have quotes round string values.

Comment: What i want to achieve there is that i have name of zone a preoblem is detected saved in variable $devname. So i just want to compare them so that if ras.H1.Z1 is detected a camera will be open if ras.H1.Z2 is detected another will open, and so on this 25 zones

Comment: I did that if ($detect == "ras.H1.Z1". there was no error but it didnt work, when i sent a message that carried the ras.H1.Z1 value

Comment: I've added some more code, try using this as it would save you having to use several tests, use the array to map the name to a zone.

Comment: I got this error: 

Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 56

I update the code i ran in my post up there

Comment: I've changed the zone bit - you had some code already there which had most of the logic.

Comment: Have added the new code to it @Nigel, Check my update on new code . I have this error higlighted
Notice: Undefined index: Z1

in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 73

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration\dataExtractor.php on line 73

Thats from the header function the $zone cap.

Comment: Would have reply since but internet connectivity was bad

Comment: This line should be  `$devname = $out->DeviceDetectionRecord->DeviceIdentification->
        DeviceName;`, all that other stuff may be OK or display purposes, but not for processing.

Comment: As for the `cannot modify header...` this is because you can't just put `header()` in the middle of a page.  If you want to display a feed from your camera, then look how to include this as an element in your page.  Look in examples for the cameras your using.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nigel , You have been very helpful. Please do you know how to use onvif web service to display the camera live feed with the information available now. I dont know about that and thats why i wanna use php header to redirect by zone mapping as you have helped me . Please send me a mail on araachap@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you. Check my updated code. I used video element tag but it doesn't stream the video and if i sent another intrusion message it stops and says: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare openCamFeed() (previously declared in

Please what could be the solution ?Thank you

Comment: hi @Nigel, i have another issue when trying to connect to the real device, Please NEW ERROR OUTPUT for the error

Comment: Looks as though the XML isn't well formed, you will need to look at the string your trying to load and check it's properly formatted.

Comment: i doubt it is well formed, i was having some truncation and when i use libxml to test i have this result in RESULT  and also my output in OUTPUT as shown up there

Comment: Hi @Nigel Ren, I finally got a solution from the OEM, for the truncated XML but getting it done is really giving me problem please can you be of help ? Check Solution message above